# Magento 2.1.9 Change Shipping method label

Tags: magento2

I am trying to update the shipping method label for UPS using the following code , but i am getting Recoverable Error: Object of class could not be converted to string

di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?><config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd"> <type name="Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\Method">
    <plugin name="pluginChangeLables" type="Test\UpsLabels\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\Method" sortOrder="10" disabled="false"/>
</type></config>
```

Method.php

```
 namespace Test\UpsLabels\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult;
 class Method {
 public function afterSetPrice($subject)
    {
      if ($subject->$this->getMethodTitle() === "UPS Ground") {
        $subject->setMethodTitle("3-5 days");
    } 

    return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an error in your code using $this. Corrected:

```
 namespace Test\UpsLabels\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult;

 class Method {

 public function afterSetPrice($subject)
    {
      if ($subject->getMethodTitle() === "UPS Ground") {
        $subject->setMethodTitle("3-5 days");
    } 

    return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Translation. Add to translation file {your_theme}/i18n/en_US.csv of Your theme string

"UPS Ground","3-5 days"

Comment: I did try with the translation but it did not work for me